# Delete unused Today Widgets

Tags: macos, finder, high-sierra

I'm trying to remove unused Today widgets from the Notification Center panel, although it's not clear on how to get rid of them (delete permanently).

[image]

The unused items show up after clicking the "Edit" button at the bottom of the Today Screen, but the only thing that the +/- seems to do is either add it to the panel or put it in a pile of unused widgets. I would like to remove some third party today widgets entirely, as I don't even have the application installed any longer.

Comment: Sounds as though the application that hosted the extension hasn't been fully uninstalled. Have a look in ~/Library/Application Support or /Library/Application Support and see if there are any files that relate to the application you installed. Also try deleting your caches.

Comment: You could also try doing a search for extension files. e.g. `sudo find / -name *.appex` or reduce that output with: `sudo find / -name *.appex | grep '.*today.*'`

Answer (score 1):

The following assumes you've got a widget called **ExampleWidget**.

1. Ensure that you've removed the application, even if it's running out of your Downloads folder.

   To do this, launch Terminal.app on your Mac and type the following commands:

   `rm -fr /Applications/ExampleWidget*`

   `rm -fr ~/Downloads/ExampleWidget*`
2. Restart Notification Center by running the following command:

   `pkill -9 -f "NotificationCenter$"`